# Setting extra long footnotes differently and in a separate part of the document

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I'd like to create a new LaTeX command:

```
\Extrafootnote{<label>}
```

When I write `\Extrafootnote{<label>}` next to a word, I'd like there to appear a footnote marked by brackets `[n]`, *i.e.* word<sup>[1]</sup>. Then, in a separated part of the document (for example, in a section named *Notes for chapter 1* that I'll create my self), I'll insert a new LaTeX command to print the footnote text:

```
\Longfootnote{<label>}{<text>}
```

I'd like to use these commands only for very long footnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elementary implementation of what you're asking for. It uses a newly-defined `longfootnote` counter, setting <sup>[n]</sup> for "long footnote" marks (via `\ExtraFootnote{<label>}`) while still keeping the original <sup>n</sup> for regular footnotes. The "long footnote" explanation is set via `\LongFootnote{<label>}{<text>}` as a list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newcounter{longfootnote}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ExtraFootnote}{ m }{%
  \refstepcounter{longfootnote}% Step longfootnote counter
  \textsuperscript{[\thelongfootnote]}% Set footnote mark
  \label{#1}% Mark with \label (for reference purposes)
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\LongFootnote}{ m m }{%
  % Set extra footnote using a list to ensure decent horizontal alignment
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item[{[\ref{#1}]}] #2
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:first}
WordA\ExtraFootnote{WordA}
WordB\footnote{WordB}
WordC\ExtraFootnote{WordC}

\section{Notes of section~\ref{sec:first}}
\LongFootnote{WordA}{\lipsum[1]}
\LongFootnote{WordC}{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

Hyperlinking in the usual way for footnotes are not supported

Comment: Thank you very much. But if I wanted the LongFootnotes numbering to stand on its own compared to normal foootnotes, what should I do? For your example, I'd like to have this: 
WordA$^{[1]}$, WordB$^{1}$, WordC$^{[2]}$. Is it possible?  Thanks again

Comment: @Puck: Sure! See the updated answer.

Comment: Thaank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book,` report`and`article` class) includes both footnotes and endnotes. I think that the following shows what you are after.

```
% endnotesprob.tex  SE 629382

\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\makepagenote  % enable page/end notes
\renewcommand{\notedivision}{\section{\notesname}} % Notes header
\renewcommand*{\notenumintext}[1]{\textsuperscript{(#1)}} % id in the text
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\subsection{#2 #3}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
Some footnoted text.\footnote{A footnote}
And another footnote.\footnote{Another}

But this is some pagenoted (endnoted) text.\pagenote{A page/end note.}
%\printpagenotes*  % page/end notes for this chapter

\chapter{Two}
Some footnoted text.\footnote{A footnote}

But this is some pagenoted (endnoted) text.\pagenote{A page/end note.}

And another pagenote. \pagenote{Second on this page.}

\chapter{Three}
Some footnoted text.\footnote{A footnote}

But this is some pagenoted (endnoted) text.\pagenote{A page/end note.}

\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

Apologies but for some unknown reason the site won`t let me post an image of the result of compiling the above MWE.